# User account does not show application assignments

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Log into Azure B2C

Click Users

Select a user

Click Applications

I created users in my B2C tenant by logging into my website using various OAuth identity providers.  So for any user selected using the above steps I expect to see at least one application listed - that being the one the user signed into when their user record was created in Azure.

When I perform the above steps I only see applications listed under my own user name.  I created all the users I see in my tenant so I know there should be apps listed with each user name.

More formally stated my questions are:

Given an Azure AD Application, how do I get a list of users that are authorized to log into that app?

Given an Azure AD User, how do I get a list of applications that user is authorized to log into?

I would like to accomplish the above tasks using Azure portal - I don't want to write script.  Also, my purpose in asking these questions is to be able to delete or disable users as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD B2C does not hold a mapping of Users who signed into an App to a specific Application Registration. By default, all users are authorized to sign into your apps if you have OAuth IdPs configured against the AAD B2C policy that allows authentication to your App.

You can use the AAD B2C Sign In logs to see which users have been logging into what applications.

Assigning or not assigning Users to Apps in the Azure Portal does not enforce any authorization, this is an Azure AD only concept and doesnt apply to Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

The process you followed(Users->select user->application) will only be able to see the applications listed under your tenant.

In the same manner when you choose an application and select the users/Groups you will only be able to see the users who have accessed your application.

Based on application/user->application you can remove the access from that application.

Regarding the

> Given an Azure AD Application, how do I get a list of users that are
> authorized to log into that app?
>
> Given an Azure AD User, how do I get a list of applications that user
> is authorized to log into?

The list of users/application authorized details are completely depend on the application consent flow.

Application developers can dictate what types of permissions are being requested and if they want to guide users through the user consent flow or the admin consent flow. If the application is provided with user consent flow based on the consent acceptance any user can access that particular application.

Admin consent flow is when an application developer directs users to the admin consent endpoint with the intent to record consent for the entire tenant. Application access grant to the requested data on behalf of the entire tenant.

For more details on the consent and permission please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience#consent-and-permissions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Sorry, but I do not understand what this has to do with consent.  The user consented to use the app otherwise I would not see their login credentials in my AD.  The problem here is that the information is not complete - I want to know what application the user logged into.

Comment: > only be able to see the applications listed under your tenant.  All the applications and users are listed in my tenant.

Comment: Regarding the Users authorization for login to applications is depended on the Consent levels and the you will only be able to see the list of application access by the user up to your tenant itself you cant see the details of external apps accessed information.

Comment: > you will only be able to see the list of application access by the user up to your tenant itself  
This is what I need to see.  I have two sites:  A.com and B.com.  You log into B.com.   After that, under users I need to see Raghavendra, under Raghavendra I need to see B.com as an Application.